# How can I download files from Rapidshare or Megaupload on Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, browser, download

How can I download Rapidshare files (I have premium access) on my Ubuntu server? It doesn't have any GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`links`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/links), or [`lynx`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/lynx), two console web browsers.  `links` is newer and more featureful; I'd try that first.

To install on Ubuntu, simply run

```
sudo apt-get install links
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

Comment: also elinks.  overview of links variants at http://elinks.or.cz/history.html

Answer (score 1):

I know what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/ There's deb package provided too.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL for the file you need, use wget or curl.

```
curl http://path.to.file.com/myfiles/file.jpg -o ~/myfile.jpg
```

Comment: i think this will fail in one of two ways: a) there'll be no direct download link for the file (on a non-premium download, you access it with a button); or b) he'll need to supply login credentials to access a direct download link.  i'm pretty sure `curl` can supply those credentials (tho i don't think `wget` can), but i don't know what those options would be ... and it'll depend on how rapidshare handles logins.  any suggestions?

Comment: you can add custom headers with wget too, so you can include the cookies from a browser (this only a theoretical possibility, and depends on many details of the website)